# php: Assigning Array Keys when creating multilevel array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I inherited the project and the data structure is a bit messy. Basically, the users input data and it's non-hierarchically structured ("pages" is not a property of "book title" but both are just values without any relation).

Now I want to create a more ordered structure, i.e. I want to list the books by author and the book details by title.

```
foreach($items as $item){
    $books[$item->author][$item->title] = array(
        "pages"      => $item->details->pages->value,
        "published"  => $item->details->year->value,
        "genres"     => $item->details->genres->value
    );
}
```

I would like to assign keys to the first two array levels. I tried `$books["author" => $item->author]["title" => $item->title]`, but got an error message.

How can I assign keys in such a situation without having to run the whole thing through multiple foreach loops?

EDIT: a note on the object structure:

The site runs on a CMS and the client built his own input form with a plugin.
All data is saved in blogposts. These blogposts have default input fields ($item->author and $item->title) and then there is a custom field option where the client input all the details, i.e. $item->details->pages->value (value as in input value of that field).

The desired structure would be something like this:

- books

  - author

    - title

      - pages
      - year
      - genres (array)
    - title

      - pages
      - year
      - genres (array)
    - title

      - pages
      - year
      - genres (array)
  - author

    - title

      - pages
      - year
      - genres (array)
    - title

      - pages
      - year
      - genres (array)
    - title

      - pages
      - year
      - genres (array)

This would allow me to loop through the whole $books array, create a  for each author and create a table that lists one $title with details per row.

Comment: What is  the error message?

Comment: have you tried $item->author->value and $item->title->value... use var_dump on  $item object to see it's structure.

Comment: I"m struggling to understand the exact transformation you seek. In your question, show an excerpt of your current structure, and the desired result for the final structure.

Comment: Let's keep it simple and start from: What is the desired resulting data structure? Using a code sample which doesn't work doesn't clarify that a lot.

Comment: I updated the description to make the request more specific.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
$books=array();
foreach($items as $item){
    $books[]=array(
       'author'=>$item->author,
       'title'=>$item->title,
       'details'=>array(
         "pages"      => $item->details->pages->value,
         "published"  => $item->details->year->value,
         "genres"     => $item->details->genres->value
        )
     );
}
```

Updated code, you just need `[]` after `[$item->author][$item->title]` so that it can be multidimensional array of your desired `author` and `title`,

```
$books=array();
foreach($items as $item){
    $books[$item->author][$item->title][] =array(
         // ---------------------------^^, this will make it nested array
         "pages"      => $item->details->pages->value,
         "published"  => $item->details->year->value,
         "genres"     => $item->details->genres->value
     );
}
```

And access the array like,

```
$str='';
foreach($books as $author=>$titleDetails){
    $str.='<h1>'.$author.'</h1>';
    foreach($titleDetails as $title=>$details){
       $str.='<br/><h2>'.$title.'</h2>';
       $str.='<br/><h3>'.$details['pages'].'</h3>';//.. and so on
    }

}
echo $str;
```

Comment: this is similar with what he tried... Would be more useful if we can take a look at the object structure.

Comment: `I would like to assign keys to the first two array levels` means that he wants to use static keys like `author` and `title`, so I've added `details` in the same array. Also, `$books` should be array of array, may be author and title are same with different publishing year.

Comment: I just updated the original question to make it a bit clearer where I want to go.

Comment: Try my updated answer, if it not works then show me your $items array.

Comment: We're getting closer, but how would I access the author in this structure? I could reference the 'pages' etc. via the key to echo them out, but not sure how to do this with the author and title values. (i.e. `<h1><?php echo $books[???] ?></h1>`)?

Comment: The current answer should work ok, let the author know and give him a treat.

Answer (score -1):

```
@media (min-width:481px){
#yiv1734505183 .yiv1734505183mobile-hide{
display:block;overflow:visible;width:auto
!important;max-height:inherit !important;min-height:auto
!important;}

}@media (min-width:481px
```